# GPU && PyTorch: на что влияет разрядность шины данных?

Tags: cuda, pytorch, nvidia, gpu

На что влияет разрядность шины данных?

У RTX 4090 она 384 бит. У Quadro A6000 она то же 384, и стоит она в 3 раза дороже наверное потому что у нее больше памяти.

А вот у Tesla A100 она составляет 5120 бит, и стоит она еще в 2 раза дороже последней, при равных прочих характеристиках (вроде как).

И если будет карта A6000, то там больше памяти, значит можно будет более большие сетки запускать, или гонять большие пачки данных.

А вот на что повлияет разрядность шины данных, которая в 10+ раз больше у A100? Ответ интересен именно в контексте обучения сеток, в частности на PyTorch. И в частности, если ставить несколько карт.

В интернете пишется, что это ускоряет обмен данными между процессором этой карты и ее памяти. Но это как-то не очень понятно, что именно и на сколько ускорится для питорча.

Так же будет интересно узнать, как сказываются упоминания в этих картах, что у них столько-то тензорных или cuda ядер.

Comment: ну примерно условно так. за один такт процессор обрабатывает 2 байта на процессоре общего применения - это 8+6=16 бит, а на графической карте сразу 5120бит. ощущаете разницу на один такт? ну и, соответственно, одновременная работа с массивами, матрицами... и много другого. а количество ядер - это собственно количество упрощённых процессоров и выполняющих эти операции. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_Google

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU

Comment: У A6000 примерно таже частота, и даже чуть по больше количество процессоров, чем у A100. Следуя логике, что производительность зависит от шины, то либо у A6000 процессоры простаивают, т.к. на них не хватает шины - лишних понаклепали. Либо у A100 кусочек лишней шины и она простаивает, т.к. ей не хватает процессоров куда ее применить. Как это соотносится?

Comment: есть узкое медленное место - постоянное чтение-запись в оперативку видеокарты данных.

Comment: В какие моменты это проявляется и как это увидеть? Я использую RTX 4090 - у нее больше всех процессоров в одном корпусе и они самые быстрые. А шина 384. При расчетах с питорчем загрузка процессора показывается 95-99%. Это означает, что шины хватает? Или процессор скрывает свои простои от системного монитора? В каких случаях ее не хватит?

Comment: так детально я не профилировал, условно поток данных по шине pci 1гб/сек, если умещается в это, то нормально. цифра у вас - хорошая. поищите profiling nvidia. вот например, нейронка, это и веса и данные, при тренировке вы подаёте на вход только данные (условно, это половина). веса на самой карте. но снимаете веса при чтении для корректировки, возможно, после одного батча.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду искать профайлер. Единственно, в нем я смогу посмотреть текущую свою железку. А мне нужно определиться со сборкой будущего сервера.

Comment: извините за вопрос, а вы уже pytorch2 используете?

Comment: Отсюда: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ поставил Stable 2.0, Linux, Cuda 11.8. Заработало без сбоев.

Answer (score 0):

вот по профилированию, но не пробовал

https://github.com/NVIDIA/PyProf

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html